# Calculation time comparison in Matlab

Tags: matlab

i need some help in doing calculation time comparison in matlab:

i have an adio file that i would like once to FFT and mesure the time it took to calculate

and compare it to the time it would take matlab to do a DFT on the signal

1) how do i make matlab sample execution time?
2) how do i forec matlab to do a DFT? 
FFt is no problem for me as i have a command for it

```
fid = 'f1lsenae.wav';
[x, fs] = audioread(fid);
x1=x(1:32000);
Y= fft(x)
plot Y
```

thanks
for the help

Assaf

Answer (score 1):

To time the execution of a code sample, use the `tic` ... `toc` construct:

```
fid = 'f1lsenae.wav';
[x, fs] = audioread(fid);
x1=x(1:32000);
tic; % Begin timing
Y= fft(x)
toc; % End timing
plot Y
```

You say "force Matlab to do a DFT". Keep in mind that FFT refers to any efficient algorithm for computing DFT. Already, Matlab's `FFT` "is the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of vector X".

Comment: thanks for the tic/toc :)
my task is to compare time execution of both DFT vs FFT
i know FFT would give me the same result as a DFT and that its the corect way  
but yet i would like to force a DFT on the same signal

Comment: @user2740068 - You can't "force" MATLAB to do a DFT.  The only available function is the FFT... which makes sense since there isn't a point to keep a less efficient algorithm for computing than DFT.  The only way is if you implement the DFT yourself, and you can either do it with two `for` loops, or you can vectorize it by considering the DFT as a matrix multiplication with a vector.